# How to use kable inside sapply in R

Tags: r, sapply, kable

My goal is to tabulate multiple columns at the same time and I used the following:

```
sapply(iris[1:4], table)
```

Next I tried to use kable to format the output, but I keep getting an error:

```
sapply(iris[1:4], knitr::kable(table))
Error in seq_len(m) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
```

So I'd like to know if it is possible to use kable inside sapply.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `lapply(iris[1:4], \(x) knitr::kable(table(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the map() function from the purrr package ?

This function applies any function to each element of a list (here, you have a data frame so it will apply the function to each column)

Personnaly, I do :

```
map(iris[1:4], function(.x){

        .x %>% knitr::kable() 
        #You can include any styling options after
})
```

Comment: `function(.x) { ... }` can be simplified as `~ { ... }` in `map`.